# Play sound from AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I'm working on an app for iPhone that uses a webview and lots of deeplinks because I'm lazy. I've configured the deeplink listening part of the app and that works great, but that method doesn't seem to be able to play systemsound or AVAudio. It doesn't error, it just doesn't play. I have this written in the method:

```
var iSaySound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("isay", ofType: "mp3")!)
var youSaySound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("yousay", ofType: "mp3")!)

var iSayPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: iSaySound, error: nil)
iSayPlayer.prepareToPlay()
iSayPlayer.play()
```

These sounds play in another part of the app fine, but not here. Does it have to do with it being in the AppDelegate? What's going on? Remember this is Swift

Comment: You should use URLForResource(WithExtension:)

Comment: Will that actually help me or are you just being a smart ass?

Comment: Makes no sense to get an url from its path if You can get the URL

Comment: What method in your app delegate are you calling this from?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30700678/2303865

Comment: `func application(application: UIApplication, handleOpenURL url: NSURL) -> Bool`

Comment: Try declaring iSayPlayer at top level

Comment: What do you mean by top level? It would error because it references iSaySound

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that the object is released before it ended playing the sound. Please check my similar question here : [Swift - AVAudioPlayer, sound doesn't play correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27911968/swift-avaudioplayer-sound-doesnt-play-correctly)

Where I've created a singleton as it was suggested.

> SoundPlayer.swift : http://pastebin.com/eX4iv3S4 .
>
> To be used like so : SoundPlayer.sharedInstance.playSound().
>
> Currently it use only one sound (because that is what I wanted), but you could easily add a parameter to the playSound method for example.

Let me know if it helped.

Comment: Would you mind summarizing this to apply to my code?

Comment: Create a `SoundPlayer.swift` file within your project. Paste the code from my link above (pastebin). Change `let soundURL = ...` with your own file. In your `AppDelegate`, where you need to play the sound, simply do `SoundPlayer.sharedInstance.playSound()`. If you need to play different sounds, just add some changes to `SoundPlayer` : add a variable, add a parameter to the `playSound()` method, within it you set soundURL, ... Clear enough ?

Comment: YES! thank you that's perfect. What was really the issue here for future reference?